# Maximal abelian subalgebra in algebra of matrices

Tags: banach-algebras

Let $A$ be the Banach algebra of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb C$. Then the subset consisting of all diagonal matrices is an abelian subalgebra. (correct me if I'm wrong).

Now I want to show that it is in fact maximal. (I am quite sure it is but maybe it isn't?).

How can I show that the diagonal matrices are a maximal abelian subalgebra? Of course the way to prove it is to assume that there exists an abelian subalgebra containing the diagonal matrices. But what then?

Comment: Let $A$ be a matrix that isn't diagonal. Construct a diagonal matrix that doesn't commute with it. Note: A matrix $A$ is not diagonal if there exists $i\ne j$ with $A_{ij}\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that if $A$ is a diagonal matrix with pairwise distinct diagonal entries and $AB=BA$, then $B$ is diagonal.